# How to transform my toggle button value to int

Tags: java, swing, transform, calculator, togglebutton

Here is my simple calculator code.Im trying to add this code something special.I want this program to: it will only use 2 even numbers or 2 odd numbers for the four arithmetical operations. For instance,If user is trying to click an even number and a odd number at the same time,my code will warn like `"You can click 2 even numbers or 2 odd numbers"`.How can I use the values that clicked by toggle buttons as int and use `if(value%2==0)` statement?

```
package tr.com.bites;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
public class CalculatorView_1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     JToggleButton[] buttons =  new JToggleButton[4];
    public CalculatorView_1() {
        initComponents();
        buttons[0]=jToggleButton12;
        buttons[1]=jToggleButton11;
        buttons[2]=jToggleButton10;
        buttons[3]=jToggleButton13;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton2 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton3 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton4 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton5 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton6 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton7 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton8 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton9 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton10 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton11 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton12 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton13 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jToggleButton14 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jToggleButton1.setText("1");
        jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton2.setText("2");
        jToggleButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton3.setText("3");
        jToggleButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton4.setText("5");
        jToggleButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton5.setText("4");
        jToggleButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton6.setText("6");
        jToggleButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton7.setText("8");
        jToggleButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton8.setText("7");
        jToggleButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton9.setText("9");
        jToggleButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton10.setText("*");
        jToggleButton10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton10ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton11.setText("-");
        jToggleButton11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton11ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton12.setText("+");
        jToggleButton12.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton12ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton13.setText("/");
        jToggleButton13.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton13ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton14.setText("=");
        jToggleButton14.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton14ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton8)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton7)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton9))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton5)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton6))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton3)))
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton14, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton12)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton11)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jToggleButton10))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton2)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton3))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton5)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton4)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton6))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton8)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton7)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton9))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton13)
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton14)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("1");
       valueCheck("1",jToggleButton1);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("2");
       valueCheck("2",jToggleButton2);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("3");
       valueCheck("3",jToggleButton3);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("4");
       valueCheck("4",jToggleButton5);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("5");
       valueCheck("5",jToggleButton4);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("6");
       valueCheck("6",jToggleButton6);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("7");
       valueCheck("7",jToggleButton8);

    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("8");
       valueCheck("8",jToggleButton7);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       processValue("9");
       valueCheck("9",jToggleButton9);
    }                                              

    private void jToggleButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
       processValue("+");
       for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("+"))
            jToggleButton12.setSelected(true);
    }                                               

    private void jToggleButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
       processValue("-");
       for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("-"))
            jToggleButton11.setSelected(true);
    }                                               

    private void jToggleButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
       processValue("*");
       for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("*"))
            jToggleButton10.setSelected(true);
    }                                               

    private void jToggleButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
       processValue("/");
       for(JToggleButton b: buttons)
           b.setSelected(false);
        if(values.contains("/"))
            jToggleButton13.setSelected(true);
    }                                               

    private void jToggleButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        long total=-1;
        int firstNumber=-1;
        int secondNumber=-1;
        String process=null;
        for (String secilenler : values) {
            if(secilenler.equals("+"))
                process="+";  
            else if(secilenler.equals("-"))
                process="-";
            else if(secilenler.equals("*"))
                process="*"; 
            else if(secilenler.equals("/"))
                process="/";    
            else
            {
                if(firstNumber==-1)
                   firstNumber= Integer.parseInt(secilenler);
                else
                    secondNumber= Integer.parseInt(secilenler);
            }
        }
           if(process.equals("+"))
                total=firstNumber+secondNumber;
            else if(process.equals("-"))
                total=firstNumber-secondNumber;
            else if(process.equals("*"))
                total=firstNumber*secondNumber;
            else 
                total=firstNumber/secondNumber;
           jTextField1.setText(""+total);
    }                                               

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]){
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CalculatorView_1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton10;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton11;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton12;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton13;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton14;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton2;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton3;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton4;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton5;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton6;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton7;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton8;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton9;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    private List<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
    public void processValue(String strValue)
    {
        if(values.contains(strValue))
            values.remove(strValue);
        else
            values.add(strValue);
    }

    private void valueCheck(String value,JToggleButton button) {

        if(values.size()>2) 
        {
            processValue(value);
            button.setSelected(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cant click 3 buttons at the same time..");
        }
    }
    private void evenOdd(int valuee,JToggleButton buton)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? You want to get the values of the buttons? Is that correct?

Comment: please post the complete code

Comment: here is the complete code

Comment: by the way the last class is empty because that's the class I am trying to write

Comment: instead of dumping a ton of code on us, please strip it to the barest essentials that demonstrate the problem - aka, post a SSCCE

Answer (score 1):

- `JToggleButton` has two states , test with `JToggleButton.isSelected`
- after code executed is required to reset state of `JToggleButton.setSelected(false)`, because Mouse / Key Events toggle with `JToggleButton`
- `JToggleButton` (`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You cant click 3 buttons at the same time..");`) isn't proper `JComponent` for Calculator (keys 0-9, + - =),  use `JButton` instead, [there are various and different ways how to do it an properly](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjava%5D%20%5Bswing%5D%20calculator), start with `ActionCommand` or `put/getClientProperty`
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: So cant I write that code with JToggleButton? I have to use JToggleButton but problem isnt solved yet

Answer (score 0):

For a simple calculator, I'd recommend using JButtons as opposed to JToggleButtons.  With JButtons, you could simply use:

```
StringBuilder intbuilder = new StringBuilder();
int firstnumber;
int secondnumber;
String operation;
button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        intbuilder.append("5");
    }
});
multiplybutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        firstnumber = Integer.parseInt(intbuilder.toString());
        operation = "*";
    }
});
```

And once the equals sign is pressed, just have perform the operation on the two numbers depending on the String operation.

Comment: I'he tried that but when I use JButtons code couldnt run the valueCheck part so I cant change JToggleButtons to JButtons

Comment: With JButtons you don't need to setSelected(false), nor do you have the issue with having more than two buttons selected at once. JButtons almost completely make the valueCheck method obsolete.

Comment: First of all, I wrote that on my phone.  There's bound to be a few typo's in there.  Second of all, I wrote it to help, not to spoonfeed code.  You get what I'm saying there.  Of course it's not going to compile.  What are the chances their button is named "multiplybutton"?

Comment: I just tested it, and it does compile.  The only problem with it is that I capitalized `actionPerformed`.